# Parse SDK Swift isParseReachable

Tags: swift, caching, parse-platform

i am trying to add Cache capability to my Parse powered app. I have a problem with the code below.

```
 if (self.objects.count == 0 || ![[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(isParseReachable)]) {
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
}
```

How can i convert this section to swift? I tried few things but they didnt work.

**![[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(isParseReachable)]**

Answer (score 0):

One of the big problems is that `performSelector` doesn't exist in Swift, so you should call the specific function directly. And to do this, and conform to Swifts type safety, you'll need to ensure your delegate is the class with the `isParseReachable` function on it.

If you have `isParseReachable` in your `.h` file for your application delegate (I've assumed your application delegate class is `AppDelegate`, and `isParseReachable` is a function/method):

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
  if (self.objects.count == 0 || !appDelegate.isParseReachable()) {
    query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i wasn't able to get this working but for now i am looking to Parse Local datastore and it does not work with the Cache at the same time.